# python does not recognise firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am recently learning python so this is my code

```
import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://cleandzapp.firebaseio.com/")
data ={
   'Name': 'nana',
   'Email':'ghjjkk',
}
result = firebase.post('cleandzapp/student',data)
print(result)
```

and this is the error i got

```
 C:\Users\Marc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Data\nana\studY\CS\2CS\S2\arduino\mini projet\CleanDzApp\firebase_test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\nana\studY\CS\2CS\S2\arduino\mini projet\CleanDzApp\firebase_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import firebase
  File "C:\Users\Marc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\firebase\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from sseclient import SSEClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sseclient'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: how did you install it? and what's the output of `pip list` in your virtual environment ([update your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64035601/edit) with these details please

Comment: in the pycharm terminal i run those two cmds pip install requests=2.24.0
and pip install python-firebase

Comment: actually i fixed that error and now i have another one (AttributeError: module 'firebase.firebase' has no attribute 'post')

Comment: change the line `import firebase`  -->  `from firebase import firebase`

Comment: also, it would be helpful for future visitors with similar issues if you should provide information on how you managed to solve the initial problem (may be post it as an answer)

Comment: i already tried with (from firebase import firebase ) and it still not working !

Comment: the initial problem  has that solution ___>thet async became a key word in the latest versions of pip so you should change the file async in this path C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\firebase into something else like nasync , also change the ---- from sync import process pool---- in init.py and firebase.py (in the same path) into to  ---- from nsync import process pool---- , that should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

the initial problem has that solution ___>the async became a key word in the latest versions of pip so you should change the file async in this path C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\firebase into something else like nasync , also change the ---- from sync import process pool---- in init.py and firebase.py (in the same path) into to ---- from nsync import process pool---- , that should solve the problem